# How to fix React Router component not updating as route changes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom for routing in my reactJs application. I have a Route, Account, that has nested routes in it. In the Account component I want to display different components based on the current route (param.id). Right now the initial component is rendering, but when I click on a link my Account component still renders that initial component regardless of that change in url. How can I get my Account component to update on the change of url. Or should I be doing something in the AccountSwitch component to recognize the change of url and update it's current value for props.match.params.id ?

```
// app.js
<Router>
    <Route path="/account" component={Account} />
</Router>

// account.js
class Account extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Link to="/account">Messages</Link>
                <Link to="/account/orders">Orders</Link>

                <Route exact path="/account" component={Messages} />
                <Route path="/account/:id" component={AccountSwitch} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

// accountSwitch.js
const AccountSwitch = props => {
    switch(props.match.params.id) {
        case '':
            return (
                <AccountMessages />
            );
        case 'orders':
            return (
                <AccountOrders />
            )
        default:
            return <span>select a page<span/>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In https://github.com/Rynebenson/og-website/blob/master/src/_components/wrappers/Account/index.js where you are using the route switch please try to use exact match for "/account" and see if that works.

Use:

```html
<Switch>
  <Route exact path={`/account`} component={AccountMessages} />
  <Route path={`/account/:id`} component={AccountSwitch} />
</Switch>
```

All while exporting try this:

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Account))

Comment: okay that worked, thank you! I'll have to read about withRouter I had never heard of it before I posted this question.

Answer (score 5):

This can also happen if you are using React Router 5 with React 18. In which case the solution is to update to React Router 6.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was the reason for me !

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried withRouter?

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

const AccountSwitch = props => {
    switch(props.match.params.id) {
        case '':
            return (
                <AccountMessages />
            );
        case 'orders':
            return (
                <AccountOrders />
            )
        default:
            return <span>select a page<span/>
    }
}
export default withRouter(AccountSwitch)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<Switch>`

```
// app.js
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/account" component={Account} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

And

```
// account.js
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

class Account extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Link to="/account">Messages</Link>
                <Link to="/account/orders">Orders</Link>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/account" component={Messages} />
                    <Route path="/account/:id" component={AccountSwitch} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Same result. When im on '/account' page I can see the Messages component. Then I click on the Link to '/account/orders' and I still see the Messages component.

Comment: I see that you missed `exact` here: https://github.com/Rynebenson/og-website/blob/master/src/_components/wrappers/Account/index.js
`<Route path={`/account`} component={AccountMessages} />` should be `                            <Route exact path={`/account`} component={AccountMessages} />'

Comment: The above answer was a good solution for me. Thank you for helping though!

Answer (score 0):

for any new user of React in 2024, if you are using react-router-dom, add this in your function of the component:

```
const location = useLocation();
```

This hook returns the current location object. So after changing the route, it will load again the page with the new props. In my project I use react-auth-kit with react-router and this really help me out.

[Oficial doc](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location)